# The python code I'm working on doesn't print anything other than the last question. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

Here is the python code I have so far:

```
import sys
import random 

# create function displayIntro, display intro to user 
def displayIntro():
    intro = str("You are a fierce mercenary traveling through a land full of Cockatrices, dragons with rooster heads, who can kill you just by looking, touching, or breathing on you. You’ve heard that the Cockatrices all live in caverns with their large piles of collected treasure. According to legend, some Cockatrices are friendly and share their treasure, while other Cockatrices are filled with hate for humans, and take out all who enter their cavern. While traveling, you approach two caverns, one with a friendly Cockatrice and the other with an angry Cockatrice, but don't know which Cockatrice is in which cavern. You must choose between the two. Good luck.")
    print(intro)
    
# create function chooseCavern, ask user which cavern they want to enter 
def chooseCavern():
    # ask user if they want to play a game 
    play = str(input("Would you like to play a game? Type yes or no:"))
    if play == "yes":
        play = True
    else:
        def exit():
            sys.exit()
    while play == True: 
        cavern = int(input("Which cavern do you choose to enter, cavern 1 or cavern 2? Type 1 or 2: "))
    # computer chooses random outcome and displays it to user 
    def checkCavern():
        computer_action = random.choice(1, 2)
        if computer_action == 1: 
            print("The cavern you entered had an unfriendly cockatrice inside. Even with all your armor and fighting power, you never stood a chance. The cockatrice opens it’s eyes from its slumber and stares you down, instantly turning you into ash.")
        else:
            print("The cavern you entered was inhabited by a friendly cockatrice. The giant, scaled dragon awakened from its slumber to tell you to take anything you desire. All it asked for in return was for you to never disturb it again. You obliged, living in immense wealth for the rest of your life.")
# ask user if they want to play again
play = str(input("Would you like to play again? Type yes or no:"))
if play == "yes":
    play = True
else:
    def exit():
        sys.exit()
```

It only prints the last lines of code, or the question "Would you like to play again? Type yes or no: " but ignores the intro, and the other questions I wrote. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you define the functions `displayIntro` and `chooseCavern` but never seem to call them anywhere

Comment: I have to have three functions, including those two, in my program. How do I rewrite my code to call them?

Comment: `displayIntro()`

Answer (score 0):

You have created the functions such as chooseCavern or displayIntro but you are not calling them.

```
# ask user if they want to play again
play = str(input("Would you like to play again? Type yes or no:"))
if play == "yes":
    play = True
else:
    def exit():
        sys.exit()
```

Only above code is working and rest is not called so that why it is only showing output you mentioned.

I does not what type of game you are making. But I made changes to your code that might be answer you are looking for or you refer from it make desirable changes in your code.

```
import sys
import random 

# create function displayIntro, display intro to user 
def displayIntro():
    intro = str("You are a fierce mercenary traveling through a land full of Cockatrices, dragons with rooster heads, who can kill you just by looking, touching, or breathing on you. You’ve heard that the Cockatrices all live in caverns with their large piles of collected treasure. According to legend, some Cockatrices are friendly and share their treasure, while other Cockatrices are filled with hate for humans, and take out all who enter their cavern. While traveling, you approach two caverns, one with a friendly Cockatrice and the other with an angry Cockatrice, but don't know which Cockatrice is in which cavern. You must choose between the two. Good luck.")
    print(intro)
    
# create function chooseCavern, ask user which cavern they want to enter 
def chooseCavern():
        # computer chooses random outcome and displays it to user 
    def checkCavern():
        computer_action = random.choice(range(1,3))
        if computer_action == 1: 
            print("The cavern you entered had an unfriendly cockatrice inside. Even with all your armor and fighting power, you never stood a chance. The cockatrice opens it’s eyes from its slumber and stares you down, instantly turning you into ash.")
        else:
            print("The cavern you entered was inhabited by a friendly cockatrice. The giant, scaled dragon awakened from its slumber to tell you to take anything you desire. All it asked for in return was for you to never disturb it again. You obliged, living in immense wealth for the rest of your life.")
    # ask user if they want to play a game 
    play = str(input("Would you like to play a game? Type yes or no:"))
    if play == "yes":
        displayIntro()
        play = True
    else:
        sys.exit()
    while play == True: 
        cavern = int(input("Which cavern do you choose to enter, cavern 1 or cavern 2? Type 1 or 2: "))
        checkCavern()
         # ask user if they want to play a game 
        play = str(input("Would you like to play a game? Type yes or no:"))
        if play == "yes":
            play = True
        else:
            sys.exit()

while(1):
    chooseCavern()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# You could use a __main__ function to call the others, although, 
# the game wouldn't really "play," it would just print out the 
# result of each function. 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    displayIntro()
    chooseCavern()
    playAgain()
```